# How to re-install default softwares and packages in Ubuntu-16.04?

Tags: 16.04, apt, upgrade, software-center

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 15.10 to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS using the command `sudo do-release-upgrade`.

During the upgrade process I lost internet connection for more than 1 hour. So I just left it there, and when I checked after a few hours I had Ubuntu 16.04 running in my system.

Still I think that I am missing some softwares and packages that should have been installed by default. Can these missing softwares be from the sites which could not be accessed during that one hour?

Is there any way to check what default softwares are missing?

Comment: try runnig `sudo apt -f install`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `ubuntu-desktop` metapackage to pull in all the default softwares for Ubuntu.

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

If it's already installed, remove it first then execute the command again. To remove

```
sudo apt remove ubuntu-desktop
```